# Converting a string and a int into a variable Python

Tags: python, variables, sikuli-script

I am currently creating a loop with sikuli. My problem is that i have a fixed variables that will go up to 15 with only the numbers changing at the end. I was looking for a way to combine the string component that is fixed with the integer which will be variable in the loop but then once concatenated have it identified as the predefined variable at the top of the code.

Any help would be awesome!

```
Dunning1 = (Pattern("Line 1.png").similar(0.97).targetOffset(445,-2))
Balance1 = (Pattern("Line 1.png").similar(0.97).targetOffset(566,-2)) 
Select1 = (Pattern("Line 1.png").similar(0.97).targetOffset(38,-1))
Dunning2 = (Pattern("Line 2.png").similar(0.97).targetOffset(442,-1))
Balance2 =(Pattern("Line 2.png").similar(0.97).targetOffset(565,2))
Select2 = (Pattern("Line 2.png").similar(0.97).targetOffset(37,-1))

while n < 3:
    DunningX = ("Dunning"+str(n)**
    print(DunningX)**
    doubleClick(DunningX)
    type("c",KEY_CTRL)
    doubleClick(DunningX)
    type("c",KEY_CTRL)
    Dunning1 = Env.getClipboard()
    BalanceX = ("Balance"+str(n))  
    doubleClick(BalanceX)
    type("c",KEY_CTRL)
    doubleClick(BalanceX)
    type("c",KEY_CTRL)
    ContractBal = Env.getClipboard()
    if Dunning1 == ContractBal:
        SelectX = ("Select"+str(n))  
        click(SelectX)
    n = n + 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but I think you're looking for this:

```
if some_condition:
    Select1 = "Select"+str(n)
else
    Select2 = "Select"+str(n)
```

any way, please consider using a list for this since using single variables is not scalable at all. It could look like this:

```
select = []
select.append(Pattern("Line 1.png").similar(0.97).targetOffset(38,-1))
select.append(Pattern("Line 2.png").similar(0.97).targetOffset(37,-1))
...
if some_condition:
    m=1
else
    m=2
select[m] = 'select'+str(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code shown i see a few issues.

1. I assume your `while n < 3` is indentation issue.
2. error with `(`:

```
DunningX = "Dunning" + str(n)
print(DunningX)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to do the following:

1 - add all the variables to a class as attributes:

```
class Variables:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Dunning1 = (Pattern("Line 1.png").similar(0.97).targetOffset(445,-2))
        self.Balance1 = (Pattern("Line 1.png").similar(0.97).targetOffset(566,-2))
```

2 - get the values dynamically by their name using `getattr` func:

```
n=1 // for example
vars = Variables()
DunningX = getattr(vars,f"Dunning{n}") //DunningX will be equal to Dunning1
```